# Global static variables in Python

Tags: python, variables, static, global

```
def Input():
    c = raw_input ('Enter data1,data2: ')
    data = c.split(',')
    return data
```

I need to use list `data` in other functions, but I don't want to enter `raw_input` everytime. How I can make `data` like a **global static** in c++ and put it everywhere where it needed?

Comment: You might consider not using these kind of global variables (hard dependencies), because they can make problems with testing and separation.

Comment: You can use `data = raw_input('Enter data1,data2: ').split(',')`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the global keyword to your function:

```
def Input():
    global data
    c = raw_input ('Enter data1,data2: ')
    data = c.split(',')
    return data
```

The `global data` statement is a declaration that makes `data` a global variable. After calling `Input()` you will be able to refer to `data` in other functions.

Comment: If data is global do you need the line `return data` ?

Comment: Python gives an error when you define global variable from a function, if define at global level it doesn't get updated from a method.

Answer (score 4):

using global variables is usually considered bad practice. It's better to use proper object orientation and wrap 'data' in a proper class / object, e.g.

```
class Questionaire(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ''

    def input(self):
        c = raw_input('Enter data1, data2:')
        self.data = c.split(',')

    def results(self):
        print "You entered", self.data

q = Questionaire()
q.input()
q.results()
```